# pivot point issue

Tags: animation

I'm trying to recreate the animation in the fig below.   Having a really hard time with pivot points though, any advice?

I create the keyframe at the final position, I select the three strands in the bundle and rotate 180deg then push "i" and click "rotation and translation" for the second keyframe.   Now all the strands rotate together but the pivot point is all wrong.  It make no difference whether I set 3D cursor on the central strand and change "transform pivot points" at the top to go to 3D cursor.  ugh.  thanks!!
https://twitter.com/eLife/status/1484901944778964993?t=BmIbFAvxXISCuV4t1KvycQ&s=19

Comment: when the animation will play, it won't take the 3D cursor into account, only the origin of the object, so as Nathan says, the best solution is probably to parent the objects to an empty and rotate this empty

Answer (score 3):

Rotating about the cursor is not really just rotation-- it is rotation, about the object origin, and translation, from its beginning point to its end point.  If you are keyframing rotation of 180 degrees about a cursor, you will not have any rotational movement about the cursor-- just moving from start to end **across** where your cursor was, while rotating about the object origin.

If you want something to rotate about a different point than its origin, parent it to something that's at that different point, and rotate that parent; if you can't parent it to something, use a child-of constraint.  Create and use an empty to parent/constrain if there is nothing better to use.

If you absolutely can't do any of that, then rotate and keyframe in smaller increments.  Rotate and keyframe in 15 degree increments, 12 times, and it will look a lot more like rotation about your cursor.